# How to show an adsense ad just below the post title in a blogger blog so that it works even on mobile version of blogger?

Tags: javascript, mobile, blogger, adsense

I want to show an adsense ad unit just below the post title on every post on my blog. I used [this tutorial](http://www.bloggertipstricks.com/adsense-below-post-title.html) for it. It is working fine on the desktop version of blogger. But on mobile version (with ?m=1), the ad is not showing. Is there a way to show the ad even on the mobile version ?

Answer (score 1):

You must checkout this helpful guide here: http://www.bloggertipstricks.com/adsense-below-post-title.html

Use responsive theme and stop showing mobile template. It will work like charm.

Comment: I have seen this guide. I have also in fact linked to this in my question itself. I'm using the default Blogger theme (which is not responsive). On mobile phone it redirects to mobile version (?m=1). Is there a way to make it work on the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Google has specific sizes for mobile versions so you can't use all the desktop supported add units for mobile devices. However, you first need to read the details about the supported and unsupported versions of Google Adsense for mobiles.

[Mobile ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/185668?hl=en)

[Ad sizes available for mobile ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68727?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution!

1. Go to the Blogger Template Design.Back up your template
2. Click Edit HTML.
3. Find- `<data:post.body/>`. It will come three times.
4. Paste your XML version Ad Code above every `<data:post.body/>`.
5. Save your template.
6. Now select custom template for mobile. And Save.

Now your Adsense ads will show just under post title in both Desktop and Mobile.

Note: If you want to show Adsense ads only below post title of mobile version template then paste the Ad Code above the first `<data:post.body/>` under- `<b:includable id='mobile-post' var='post'>`.